# Use of 802.1x security option in network?

Tags: networking

I was passing through network settings and noticed this option 802.1x security for this connection? Available to tick. I did never pay any attention to this option untill now, I just want to know what does this option exactly stands for? Security against what/for what? I got wired connection and wonder do I really need to activate it and if so then why? Just in short help would be appreciated, because I was googling and I didn't find exact answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE 802.1x is a port-based Network Access Control mechanism for connecting to A network based on smart card or domain certificate.

Typical usage are seen in large organizational network where each machine is given an unique certificate. While logging into/ connecting the network, the authenticator verifies the certificate and let the machine connect to the network.

It is useful when you are in large LAN and you need to secure the environment. The scope of the protocol is limited to LAN/WLAN.

More info : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X

Comment: In other words, if you don't have a large corporate switch that can use or requires it, then you don't tick the box ;)